# Is it possible in Kafka to receive message at consumer side whenever the message arrives at a topic instead of polling at certian interval

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying to explore whether KafkaConsumer can receive message whenever message arrives at a topic instead of polling at certain time interval. I know Kafka is a pull mechanism at consumer side, is it possible to achieve the said requirement as I am not sure when the message will arrive and not sure what optimized value to set as poll time interval?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible even because it's how the underneath Kafka protocol works on the wire. It's a pure request/response based protocol, so there is no "push" mechanism from the broker to the client.
Think that, if a leader for a partition changes, for example, the consumer isn't aware of that until it tries to fetch messages (or get metadata) and the broker replies that the leader is changed (so there is no alert pushed from the broker to the consumer to say "I'm not the leader anymore" just right after it happens). This is only an example for explaining better what's the nature of the protocol.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by ppatierno it's not possible. However you can create consumer clients with low latency, near to real time. There are multiple options to achieve it. Following are some of it.

1. Kafka stream
2. Apache Flume
3. Apache Spark (Spark continuous streaming (latency of ~1ms))

Kafka stream is most simple way to go as it doesn't need any additional set up like others.

Answer (score 0):

By design, Kafka Consumer follows a pull model. So, it is not possible to get the "trigger" on message arrival.
As far as poll time interval is concerned, it should be configured depending on the throughput of the topic consumed and how many messages you want to process in one go. Value of 50ms works well for most applications.